# Is the RFC 3501 SEARCH command used in production in major ways?

Tags: email, rfc

Most E-Mail clients (e.g. Thunderbird) provide their own search functionality. [RFC 3501](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501) proposes a SEARCH command that is quite elaborate:

```
  The SEARCH command searches the mailbox for messages that match
  the given searching criteria.  Searching criteria consist of one
  or more search keys. […]
```

Is the SEARCH command implemented and used by widely used clients and tools? I did a lot of digging but found mostly custom implemented, sometimes open-source searches that work offline.

Is this command a good alternative to a separate search engine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is the SEARCH command implemented and used by widely used clients and tools?

Yes, some mail user agents (MUA) use the `SEARCH` command to obtain a mailbox/folder status, and/or use it for it's intended purpose: to search.

I work at a company that provides mail services like IMAP. Looking at our statistics, I can see that about 6% of all IMAP commands we receive are `SEARCH` commands.

> Is this command a good alternative to a separate search engine?

Well, the answer depends on your application.  If your application offers POP3 support, you'll most certainly need a separate search engine anyways.  However, if your application only supports IMAP and a search engine would be the only reason to cache all messages locally, IMAP `SEARCH` might work for you and save you a ton of work.
In any case, I'd say that the features `SEARCH` offers are enough for nearly all users and situations.

Comment: Thanks! This was the answer I was looking for... 6% is more than I expected, to be honest! Is that number changing in any way? Is there a notable trend?

Comment: I agree, these 6% are more than one would think. IIRC it was the mail app on iOS that frequently sends SEARCH commands to determine deleted messages. 
I do not see any notable trend in the data I have.